# Rewriting this nested for loop for better time complexity

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

I am trying to optimize the following nested for loops for a smaller amount of iterations. I feel it is very inefficient as it stands and want to think there is a better way of doing this that takes less iterations.

We have vectors M and N

```
  M = 1:74
  N = 1:150

  for n = 1:150
      for m = 1:74
          matrix(m,n) = m/n
```

If I am not mistaken this nested for loop has a time complexity of m*n being 74x150 = 11,100. I know there has to be a better way of populating the matrix(m,n) but can't think of a way of actually doing so. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried thinking about levering vectorization and reducing the time complexity to something like (m+n) vs the current (m*n) but don't know how that looks like in practice. I wouldn't wanna go into a rabbit hole before asking

Comment: If you're going to fill a 74x150 matrix, there's absolutely no way around the fact that there are going to be 11,100 entries needed to be filled in, regardless of data structure or iteration method. The time complexity will always be *O(m x n)*. If only a minority of entries are likely to be accessed, however, consider creating a matrix class where entries are lazily evaluated.

Comment: " I know there has to be a better way of populating the matrix(m,n) " there isn't, not algorithmically. Note, vectorization doesn't change the algorithmic complexity. Also, **please post real Python code, not pseudocode**

Comment: You can save `M` divisions because `matrix[j][i] = 1` for `1 <= i <= M`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using meshgrid approach? While actually the time complexity for meshgrid formation will be m*n but later on you can use vectorization to improve performance.
The element-wise division is where the vectorization really shines, as it is much more efficient than explicitly looping over each element.

```
M = np.arange(1, 75)
N = np.arange(1, 151)


MMESH, NMESH = np.meshgrid(M, N)

matrix = MMESH / NMESH

matrix_list = matrix.tolist()
```

I dont think the time complexity can be reduced below m*n.

Comment: you can do it in one line with broadcasting `matrix = np.arange(1, 75)[:, np.newaxis] / np.arange(1, 151)[np.newaxis, :]`